# Как составить запрос telegram api users.getFullUser

Tags: python, telegram

Я пытаюсь использовать метод getFullUser

```python
import requests as r


token = '666666666:66666666666666666666'
user_id = 666666666
method = 'getFullUser'

resp = r.post(
    url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/{}'.format(token, method),
    data={'id': user_id}
).json()

print(resp)
```

сервер возвращает:

```html
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 404, 'description': 'Not Found'}
```

Как правильно составить запрос?

Answer (score 2):

Увы, для ботов метод `getFullUser` не доступен. Список доступных методов можно посмотреть в документации: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods.

Дополнительный пруф на соседнем форуме: https://telegrammy.net/group/botoid/page840.htm#83968

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы пользоваться этой функцией вам необходим API telegram (не бот api). Для его получения идём на [официальный сайт telegram](https://my.telegram.org/apps). Забиваем номер телефона и получаем api и api hash. Способа для взаимодействия с telegram через запросы я не нашёл. Поэтому далее устанавливаем библиотеку telethon для работы с api телеги.
Далее пишем подобную конструкцию: `

```
user = '@' + user
with TelegramClient('ваш ник', Api, Hash) as client:
     full = client(GetFullUserRequest(user))`
```

Важно! Ваш ник вводится без собаки, а ники юзеров, которые вы хотите получить с собакой
Затем из переменной full можно получать данные о юзере. Например вот так:`id = full.user.id`